# Visual Studio Code Error - Failed to load jshint library

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint

Every time Visual Studio Code started or loaded it shows an error message:
"**Failed to load jshint library. Please install jshint in your workspace folder using 'npm install jshint' or globally using 'npm install -g jshint' and then press Retry**". 
Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need to follow the prompt and install jshint.

For just the workspace

`npm install jshint`

or

For all your workspaces

`npm install -g jshint`

Comment: I tried for all workspaces with the second command; it works. Thanks.

Comment: Did not work for me. On Windows 7, I installed node.js which includes npm. Then I ran `npm install jshint` (and also tried the global install). But I still get the error message from the question. Any other things I have to set up?

Comment: Okay, I think it's working now. For some reason I thought I would have to run the command as admin. But it only worked after running it as user.

Comment: The suggested commands only worked for me when they was issued in the terminal of VS Code itself.

Comment: I'm using VS Code with python and I am getting this same message.  I installed for the workspace but then when I need to create a new workspace I need to do it all over again.  Is there a way to fix this for all newly created workspaces without installing globally?  Or, do I even need it for my Python workspace?

Comment: Following the advice on [this page](https://newbedev.com/visual-studio-code-error-failed-to-load-jshint-library), in addition to doing the above, I had to add two lines to VSC's settings file, `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`: `"jshint.packageManager": "npm"` and `"jshint.nodePath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/"`. (The page had yarn as the package manager, but I use npm.) Then I closed and restarted VSC, and got a dialog asking me how I wanted to use the jshint library; I clicked the "Allow Everywhere" option.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem while I had installed `jshint` using `yarn` globally (`yarn global add jshint`). I added the following properties to `settings.json` for `User` to solve the problem:

```
"jshint.packageManager": "yarn",
"jshint.nodePath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/"
```

The first property i.e. `jshint.packageManager` specifies that `yarn` is used to manage `node` packages instead of `npm`. The second one i.e. `jshint.nodePath` specifies the path of `jshint` installation. To check if `jshint` is loaded successfully, I opened Command pallet (  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>) and ran command `JSHint: Show output` which showed this message in the output:

```
jshint library loaded from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint/src/jshint.js
```

It indicated that the problem was resolved. Afterwards, the `jshint` messages appeared in `*.js` files.

Comment: Thanks! For me, the answer was to simply set nodePath for jshint. The error message was  (wrongly) telling me to install jshint because it couldn't find the global node_modules folder.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open `cmdr` or the Git bash terminal and enter `npm install -g jshint`, then exit VS code and re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

For applying the changes to Global scope, and not only to a specific Workspace, use the following command in terminal:-

```
npm install -g jshint
```

For a particular workspace, use the following command in terminal:-

```
npm install jshint
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sudo before `npm install jshint`

For the current workspace
`sudo npm install jshint`
or

For all your workspaces
`sudo npm install -g jshint`

Using `sudo` with a command in LINUX/UNIX generally gives you the permissions to root level.
The root user has permission to access, modify or delete almost any file on your computer. Normal user accounts can access, modify or delete fewer files. This restrictions on normal user accounts are to protect your computer from unauthorized and harmful programs or users.

Thus, running the installation command with `sudo` gives you the permissions of the superuser, and allows you to modify files that your normal user doesn't have permission to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling using "npm uninstall" and follow the link - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint for reinstalling.